# Lightbox 2.51 not working correctly in any browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

**ANSWER**
Okay everyone, found the solution (Since I'm a new user, it won't let me answer my own question in less than 8 hours, sorry):

Turns out the newest version of LightBox, v2.51, only supports jQuery v1.7.2. All I did was download that version of jQuery and use it instead of the newest version and it worked right away.

Sort of an amateur mistake to not test the jQuery version it was built for, I guess ;)

Thanks for everyone who viewed and the attempts to answer!

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

My first stackoverflow post, so let me just get right down to it!

I'm trying to use Lightbox v2.51 on my site, locally, so I tried to make a quick and easy concept just to see how it worked before I actually tried to implement it on my site.

So, here I have a simple 'gallery.htm' file with the content below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="engine/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="images/title.gif" rel="lightbox" title="The main graphic">Test</a>
    </div>
<script src="engine/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="engine/lightbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I click on the 'Test' link, it is supposed to load up the referenced image link in lightbox, black out the screen and then animate a div which includes the image, blown up to full view. The screen fades to dark, but I don't get anything else afterwards. Here is a [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7UY3.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Ani.png) shot. When I click on the link, as you can see, the screen darkens but nothing else happens, the image isn't loaded at all.

The jQuery version is 1.9.1 and it is stored locally just for my localhost testing purposes, it is called from the Google ajax host when it is on the live site.

The scripts and styles are located in the local folder "engine". All of the files are named correctly, and when using Google Chrome, I completely load the page and hold SHIFT+CTRL+J to check the console for errors, but everything is loading perfect.

Any help is appreciated, THANK YOU! :)

Comment: if you remove `rel="lightbox"`, does it show the image? Possibly the link is broken?!

Comment: Yes, it shows the image if I remove the rel="lightbox".

Comment: Don't put the answer in the question. Remove the answer from the question and then post an answer with the same text.

Comment: IcyFlame: I tried posting an answer, but since I'm a new user it won't let me post an answer for up to 8 hours after I've posted a question. What to do, what to do? :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the given jQuery package which comes with your lightbox download! 
This works!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="screen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lightbox.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="1.jpg" rel="lightbox">TestLink</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a bunch for the speedy reply! :) That was pretty much what I'd figured out! I appreciate it!